# AngularJS toggling header works only if changed in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="schedule">  
    <!-- Header info -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Schedule title -->
        <div class="title" ng-click="toggleHeader()">
            <span ng-hide="isScheduleVisible">{{ schedule.name }} (Open to View)</span>
            <input ng-model="schedule.name" class="schedule-name" ng-show="isScheduleVisible"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Action menu items go here -->
        <div class="actions" ng-show="isScheduleVisible"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Schedule Info -->
    <div class="row" ng-show="isScheduleVisible">
        <!-- This is the time on the left of the table -->
        <div id="times"></div>

        <!-- Conditions for the Schedule -->
        <div id="conditions"></div>

        <!-- Shifts of the Schedule -->
        <div class="shifts"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to toggle the content by clicking the "title" (see below for the open/close state snapshot). Right now, as you can see, I call a function `toggleHeader()` in my controller, and all it does is:

```
$scope.toggleHeader = function()
{
    $scope.isScheduleVisible = ! $scope.isScheduleVisible;
}
```

I want to replace it with `ng-click="isScheduleVisible = !isScheduleVisible"`. However, this does not work. This will only toggle the header (the grey banner) and not the actual content (the schedule).

Why?!

[image]

Comment: Is the markup exactly the same as the one you are actually using? If the `isScheduleVisible = !isScheduleVisible` does not work, it seems like the header block and content block have different scopes.

Comment: Yes, the markup is exactly as I am currently using it. If the header and the content have different scopes, then why does this work when I assign it in the controller? What difference does that make exactly?!

Comment: That probably because the `$scope` in the controller might be a third one and it is a parent of those two scopes. Child scopes will see values of their parent. Note that this is a guess, I still doesn't notice anything in your template and introduce such scopes.

Comment: Could you check the DOM in DevTools and try looking for elements with `class="ng-scope"`?